# Flask hangs the main thread

Tags: python, flask

I want to use the Flask as my RESTful API server, but the main thread hangs and it doesn't execute the code after the `app.run()`.

**In util/restAPI.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('__name__')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

**In main.py**

```
from util import restAPI

if __name__ == "__main__":
   restAPI.app.run()
   print "haha"
```

Should I use threads or something else to help me?

Comment: `app = Flask(__name__)`  `__name__` is not string

Comment: With app.run() you execute Flask and the code after this will not get executed as long as Flask is running (which is actually until it is terminated). But what do you want to achieve at all?

Comment: `restAPI.app.run()` is a blocking function.

Comment: In my main.py, it will collect the data and store to the file.
In my restAPI.py,it will get the data from the file and show as json.
so I want to run only one python script(main.py) to make two things work.

Comment: And main.py is a loop function to get the file, so I can't add the app.run() the end of program. It only terminates when I stop it with ctrl+c.

Comment: And I also want to run main.py to create a web(127.0.0.1) to use API getting the information